# Short comments delimited with spaces appear to be above the character minimum

Tags: bug, status-declined, comments, character-limit

[image]

Notice that the gray text says that the comment is long enough, but the dialog prevents you from submitting.

Comment: The client side validation is not stripping spaces. The server side validation does. That is NOT a bug in any way.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The gray text should still count the length minus the spaces.

Comment: This is too minor to spend any time, in my opinion. As Jeff says: don't do that.

Comment: Not going to fix something this minor - this is not a common scenario and what you see can be reasonably expected behavior.